# How GeneXus handle DeviceSubscriptionExpired in Push Notifications?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

Some users reported they are not receiving notifications, I believe it's related to "ErrCode 3 - DeviceSubscriptionExpired" since I find out this in the logs (DeviceToken omitted):

```
ERROR SDAPI.Notifications - SetResult - ErrCode 3 - DeviceSubscriptionExpired - APA91******
```

What action my program need to take when get this error?

I'm already updating the DeviceToken using NotificationsRegistrationHandler.

Gx 15 U2 C#

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have Push Notifications up and running with GeneXus, is using GeneXus OneSignal implementation.
We recommend to use OneSignal GeneXus implementation instead of 'SDAPi.Notifications'

Take a look [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30621,HowTo%3A%20Push%20Notifications%20Using%20OneSignal)